# Помогите, пожалуйста, отцентрировать матрицу (Java)

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Это мой код.

Должно быть как на 2 рисунке
У меня как на первом.

Большое спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MatrixPrint {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];

        for (int i = 0, k = 5, x = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            k--;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++, x++) {
                matrix[i][j] = x;
                if (i == j || j == k)
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                else
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: посмотрите на https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я пересмотрела, но, к сожалению, к ответу не дошла. Может, у вас есть идеи?

Comment: Есть очевидная идея просто добавит пробел перед `*` и перед числом, если оно меньше 10.

Comment: При форматировании можно задавать выравнивание - вот это и надо сделать

Comment: @NewJavaLearner `String.format("%02d ", matrix[i][j])`  и `String.format("%02s ", "*")`, изучайте строку форматирования

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить табуляции

if (i == j || j == k)   System.out.print("\t* ");

else                    System.out.print("\t" + matrix[i][j] + " ");

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.